# temporary hang with remote shells keeping the connection

Tags: networking, redhat, troubleshooting

We are having some trouble on our machine having Red Hat 6.2 Enterprise.

For just about 1 minute this is what happens:

1. during that minute my SSH shell are frozen and we cannot do anything
2. at the end of that minute all previous connections are still there and we can keep on working like usual.
3. during that minute we can't establish any new connection.

First thing I though is something like some burst or heavy network traffic taking the entire bandwidth.

What log or where can I have a look to gather further evidence? Any suggestion is very well appreciated.

Regards

AFG

Comment: What does a dump of the network traffic seen by the server in question look like during that minute? What does the load look like then? What does the client's network traffic look like if it tries to start a new connection during that minute?

Comment: Probably I need to put in place a TCPDUMP to get this information if this happens again. That records activities when it happens...I have no idea where to gather data AFTER the event happened.

Comment: You can't gather transient network information after the fact unless something was monitoring during the event that you can query for its data. So yes, you will need to be actively dumping traffic during one of these events. Are they random?

Comment: @Etan. Hi I am not sure but looks like they manifest more or less at the same time. I need to see what happens today while I'll put in place a TCPDUMP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think the network might be saturated, you need to monitor it. Everything - the server's NIC(s), the connection(s), and any intermediate devices like routers, switches, etc. If any of those is overloaded, you'll have problems.

It could have nothing at all to do with the network, as well. The CPU or IO subsystem could be pegged. You need to look at the whole server. What hardware is the server?

Comment: HI. Our server is a 4 core CPU, 4 hard disks Raid 5, 16 GB Ram + 2 network cards.

Comment: OK - do you have any performance monitoring in place for the server, as I described?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Based on chat with people I need to have monitors in place. What tool or monitor do you suggest?

Comment: Unanswerable in short form, which is why we don't like Shopping Questions. Depends on your needs, infrastructure, and budget, and probably other constraints. Lots of people like Nagios and Zabbix.